# CS50 Pset5 check() counting too many words as misspelled

Tags: c, trie, cs50

I have loaded the dictionary into a tree structure and successfully gotten speller.c to compile with the following implementations of load() and check().

However, when I run the program, an incorrect number of words are counted as misspelled by my check() function. (In the case of lalaland.txt, it's 17187 words out of 17756).

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code and would be extremely grateful to anyone who could help point me in the right direction.

```
typedef struct node
{
  bool isword;
  struct node *children[27];
}
node;
node *root = NULL;

// Function returns the position of any given letter in the alphabet e.g. a = 1, b = 2 etc. Returns 0 for an apostrophe.
int index(char letter)
{
    if (isalpha(letter))
    {
        int i = letter - 96;
        return i;
    }

    return 0;
}


// Keeps track of number of words loaded into dictionary.
unsigned int wordno = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{

    char newword[LENGTH + 1];
    node *temp = root;

    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)
    {
        //Makes each letter of the input lowercase and inserts it into a new array.
         newword[j] = tolower(word[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        //Finds the position of the character in the alphabet by making a call to index().
        int letter = index(newword[i]);

        if (temp->children[letter] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
           temp = temp->children[letter];
        }

    }

    if (temp->isword == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

     return false;

}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
  FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

  root = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
  node *temp = root;

  if (dict == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not load dictionary.\n");
    return false;
  }

  char word[LENGTH+1];


  while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        int letter = index(word[i]);

        if (temp->children[letter] == NULL)
        {
            temp->children[letter] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

            if ((temp->children[letter]) == NULL)
            {
                unload();
                return false;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->children[letter];

    }

    temp->isword = true;
    wordno++;


   }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: `node *temp = root;` seems like it belongs inside `while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)` rather than before it.

Comment: @chux Thank you so much! That was exactly what was wrong. My code now works fine.

Comment: You can post an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: the name: `LENGTH` is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements, so does not compile!  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files that you included?

Comment: the posted code is missing the definition of the function: `unload()`

Comment: the variable `index` is defined in the header file: `string.h` as the name of a function.  So you must not use `index` as the name of a local function

Comment: regarding: `for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++)`  this is comparing a `int` to the 'unsigned long' value returned from `strlen()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node *temp = root;
```

should be placed inside this while loop:

```
while (fscanf(dict, "%s", word) != EOF)
```

By doing this, you allow temp to go back and point to the root node each time the loop begins iterating over a new word in the file.